# Clarity and clarification tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The [clarity](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarity) and [clarification](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification) tags seem to really be about the same thing.  The [cloudy](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudy) tag also seems a bit redundant and appears with each of these tags.

Should tag synonyms be created for these?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no longer sure about this.

I think it may make more sense for [clarification](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification) to be a parent of [clear](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clear) and [fining](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fining) but [clarity](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarity) could be a more general concept.

Also, after looking more closely at the questions, [cloudy](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudy) seems to be more about people explaining cloudiness (rather than necessarily getting rid of it).  So I'm not sure that fits in either.

Adding an excerpt to better define all of them is probably a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification and Fining are related; fining being a method of speeding up clarification.

I am equally unsure, Clarity is a concept that ranges from Clear to Cloudy.

I second the idea of adding an excerpt to these tags to help clarify the situation.